# Apache RewriteCond of alternative filename based on mangling of the original REQUEST_FILENAME string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got an application that's arranged with the `site/public` as the document root and composer putting code and modules in `site/vendors`.

By default images are in `site/public/images/<file>` which shows up as `http://<host>/images/<file>`

What I'm trying to achieve is to have requests for static files, like images or javascript ie `http://<host>/images/<module>/<path>` to actually get the files from `site/vendors/<module>/images/<path>`.

Now I know I can't use rewrite rules to redirect the request outside of document root, so I use `site/public/.htaccess` to redirect appropriate requests to `site/public/vendorModulesStaticLookup.php` which will handle that bit, like this...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascript)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(images|javascript)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ vendorModulesStaticLookup.php?type=$1&module=$2&path=$3 [NC,L]
```

Where vendorModulesStaticLookup.php is essentially (I'm skipping all the sanity testing)

```
<?php
$targetFile = "site/vendor/$module/$type/$path";

$mimetype = mime_content_type($targetFile);
if (!empty($mimetype)) {
  header("Content-Type: $mimetype");
}
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($targetFile));
$retval = @readfile($targetFile);
if ($retval === FALSE) {
  $lastError = error_get_last();
  $errorMessage = @$lastError['message'];
  error_log(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__." Something went wrong attempting to readfile($targetFile): ".$errorMessage);
}
?>
```

And that works, however if the path specified is invalid, and `$targetFile` doesn't exist, it returns a blank page, rather than my pretty 404 page (handled elsewhere in the `.htaccess` via a RewriteCond !-f

So what I want to do, is have a `RewriteCond` rule which tests that the file `site/vendors/<module>/<type>/<path>` exists before I execute the `RewriteRule`  so bad requests, don't get sent to `vendorModulesStaticLookup.php` in the first place.

In the above example `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will be either `/var/www/html/site/<path>` or `/u/sites/<path>` depending on whether it's production or development, so what I want to do is to be able to completely mangle `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` before doing a `-f` test as part of a `RewriteCond`.

Is that possible?

Comment: 1) is there images/ folder under document root? 2) do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: there is `site/vendor/modules/module/images` which will come from the `module/images` folder as brought in by composer.  There is also a `site/public/images` and `site/public/javascript` folder which are what you get when you visit http://sitename/images and http://sitename/javascript and yes I can change the apache .conf files, but the `public/.htaccess` file has all the other rewrites as used by Zend Framwork and the various aliases sites in our application